# Не могу получить значение из функции.Возвращает undifined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

ДЕлаю дирекшион получаю ответ .

```
var map;

function initMap() {

     var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', 40.401362, 49.842257, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', 40.407498, 49.789642, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', 40.397760, 49.925941, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', 40.431724, 50.051327, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach',40.368523, 50.200322, 1]
    ];
      var marker, i;



     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });


 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
  }
   // calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay);
     var drivers = [];  




  //  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(7).children().val());


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,des) {
 directionsService.route({ 
    origin: {lat: 40.395379, lng: 49.818631},  
    destination: des ,  
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var routes=response.routes;
      var leg =routes[0].legs;
       var lenght = leg[0].distance.text;
       var duration = leg[0].duration;
       return leg[0].duration.text;

    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}


   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on('click','.button', function(){
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        console.log(alert(calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay, new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]))))  ;

            } 
        });
});
}
```

Comment: куда нить на jsfiddle запилите, чтобы было понятнее, возможно часть вы выполняете в дом-риди, другую часть до дом-риди.  Мало инфы. Понятно одно, до вызова duration она либо не инициализирована, либо ваша первая функция вернула туда undefined

Comment: а если после вызывания функции написать в `console` duration; вернет чтото? 
я думаю `duration = leg[0].duration.text;` не успевает выполниться

Comment: щас секунду я залбю и вам покажу

Comment: @L.Vadim  да тогда он выполняется в само функции duration выполняется но стоит мне его достать огттуда то получаю undifined

Comment: Щас залью на jsfdiddle

Comment: @L.Vadim  залил сюда весь свой код посмотрит е пожалуйста

Comment: @L.Vadim почему я не могу взять значение durationa eıt ujkjde ckjvfk ə

Comment: @elik попробуйте после этого `var duration = leg[0].duration;` в функции написать `console.log(duration)`, и вы все попймете

Comment: @L.Vadim консоль отображает массив с 2 переменными временем и расстоянием

Comment: @L.Vadim мне надо сам массив передавать ?

Comment: когда он онпичатывается до или после undefined

Comment: @L.Vadim  ааа цикл проходит быстрее чем данные поступают

Comment: @L.Vadim как быть  в таком случае ?чтобы посоветовали ?

Comment: @elik совсем перепутал все, надо так `setTimeout(function(){
console.log(duration);
},1000)` где duration глобальная

Comment: @L.Vadim да получилось ...Спасибо Большое !!!!оформите как ответ что я принял его за правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем `duration` глобальной.
после того как срабатывает `duration = leg[0].duration;`
ожидаем 1 сек, и достаем `duration`

вот код:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
 console.log(duration); 
},1000);
```